# Save edited data laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, save

I'd like to ask you how i can save my edited data when im using this table

> peminjaman |id|tgl_pinjam|lama_pinjam|tgl_hrs_kembali|status_pinjam|totalBayar|diskon|jml_bayar|status_pembayaran|tgl_pengembalian|denda|ket_kembali|id_member

Then here is my route:

```
Route::post('staff-view-peminjaman/update/{id}', 'PeminjamanController@update');
```

Here is my controller

```
function update($id) {
    $peminjaman = \peminjaman::find($id);
    $peminjaman->tgl_pinjam = \Input::get('tgl_pinjam');
    $peminjaman->lama_pinjam = \Input::get('lama_pinjam');
    $peminjaman->tgl_hrs_kembali = \Input::get('tgl_hrs_kembali');
    $peminjaman->status_pinjam = \Input::get('status_pinjam');
    $peminjaman->status_pembayaran = \Input::get('status_pembayaran');
    $peminjaman->totalBayar = \Input::get('totalBayar');
    $peminjaman->jml_bayar = \Input::get('jumlahBayar');
    $peminjaman->tgl_pengembalian = \Input::get('tgl_pengembalian');
    $peminjaman->denda = \Input::get('denda');
    $peminjaman->ket_kembali = \Input::get('ket_kembali');
    $peminjaman->id_member = \Input::get('id_member');
    $peminjaman->save();
    return \Redirect::to('staff-view-peminjaman');
}
```

And here is my view for editing

```
<form method="post" role="form" action="{{ action ('Controller\Staff\PeminjamanController@update'),$peminjaman->id }}">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputTglPinjam">Tanggal Pinjam</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputTglPinjam" placeholder="Tanggal Pinjam" name="tgl_pinjam" value="{{ $peminjaman->tgl_pinjam }}">
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="exampleInputLamaPinjam">Lama Pinjam</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputLamaPinjam" placeholder="Lama Pinjam" name="lama_pinjam" value="{{ $peminjaman->lama_pinjam }}">
</div> 
.............
<p>Bayar Pengembalian: <div id="bayar" name="bayar"></div></p>
```

And I have this button to save

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="buttonSimpan">Simpan</button>
```

and this javascript to calculate the price

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#exampleInputTglPengembalian').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
    });

    $("#exampleInputDenda").change(function() {
        var bayar = parseInt("0");
        var totalBayar = parseInt($("#inputTotalBayar").val());
        var jumlahBayar = parseInt($("#inputJumlahBayar").val());
        var denda = parseInt($("#exampleInputDenda").val());
        bayar = bayar + denda + totalBayar - jumlahBayar;
        $("#bayar").html(bayar);
    });

});
```

Somehow it doesn't work and give me this warning

> Creating default object from empty value

I'd love to know how to solve it but i dunno what to do
if you know, I hope you are willing to tell me what to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because the ID isn't getting passed through properly, so the model can't find the record. Your syntax is slightly wrong when defining the action. It should be this:

```
<form method="post" role="form" action="{{ action('Controller\Staff\PeminjamanController@update', array('id' => $peminjaman->id)) }}">
```

Also to prevent that error from happening, your code should think about using findOrFail when updating records.

```
 $peminjaman = \peminjaman::findOrFail($id);
```

Comment: Owh... thank you for your help. This work just like i want. Wish you all the best... aamiin

Comment: This is how you accept an answer on StackOverflow... http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png